# Search and Get count for tree structured matched object in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, backend

I am new to backend. I am using golang with mongodb. I have collection whose an array named meta is saved as tree structure. I want get count if objectid for which I am searching matches the id inside the meta array of children. I have attached a screenshot for the understanding.

I am unable to write query. I want to compare the id with every moduleid inside the meta and child array for all documents and if matches it should return the count of matched results.

[image]

I am trying to query mongodb and unable to find that how I can iterate and compare id at every child node. I have found a solution to apply aggregation pipeline but I am unable to understand this concept.